# Getting specific data in a JSON format using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a JSON format in a manner.But I want to get only specific data in a JSON format.

Here is my code.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in studyTeamObj" align="center">
    <td>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="x.designation" ng-options="item as item.Emp_Name for item in createStudyObj.Study_User">
        <option value=""></option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      {{x.designation.Emp_Id}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{x.designation.Designation}}
    </td>
    <td class="mdrf-add-row-col">
      <i class="fa  fa-minus-circle" data-ng-click="deleteMem($index)"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is my controller.

```
$scope.studyTeamObj = [
    { }
];

$scope.addStudyTeam = function () {
    $scope.studyTeamObj.push({
        designation:'', 
    });
}

var formList = [];
formList.push(                                
    { Study_Team: $scope.studyTeamObj },                
);
```

While adding I am getting this json format

```
{
  "Study_Team": [
    {
      "designation": {
        "Emp_Name": "mdrf",
        "Emp_Id": 2,
        "Designation": "Research Dietitian",
        "DesignationID": 20
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need to get like this,

```
{
  "Study_Team":[
    {
      "Study_Id":"1",
      "DesignationID":"20",
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help?

```
createStudyService.saveStudy(data).then(function (response) 
{ if (response.data === 'Study Master Saved Successfully') 
{ alertService.showDialog('md', 'Message', 'Study has been created', 'success', 'studyList');
 } else
 { alertService.showDialog('sm', 'Alert', 'Study Details Not Added Successfully', 'warning'); }
```

Comment: Could you tidy up your codes please?

Comment: Can't you write a mapper to construct the required object from the existing JSON object? Or do you have a problem in writing the mapper?

Comment: @lin tidy complete.

Comment: The best way is to solve this on the API callback directly. I would not transform the data you recive. It sounds like a problem due to the API design. I also would stay with the attributes type like "number" and not transform your numbers into strings like `"DesignationID":"20"`. So, why do you need the data transform?

Comment: I mistyped..Actually the format is "DesignationID":20,

Comment: I need to store in the database which has only Emp_id and Designation_Id

Comment: Yea, ok this is good. But where you send your API request for storing? Thats the point where you need to map your data attributes. Could you add the form logic, view and request logic to your question?

Comment: var data = {
            INSERT: formList
        };

Comment: createStudyService.saveStudy(data).then(function (response) {
 
            {
                if (response.data === 'Study Master Saved Successfully')
                {
                    alertService.showDialog('md', 'Message', 'Study has been created', 'success', 'studyList');
                } else
                {
                    alertService.showDialog('sm', 'Alert', 'Study Details Not Added Successfully', 'warning');
                }
            }

Comment: I need to change in the object

Comment: Could you please add this to your questions. Its worst to put this into a comment.

Comment: Where is `createStudyService.saveStudy(data)` called from` Please add all you codes to make your problem reproduceable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
createStudyService.saveStudy(data).then(function (response)  
{ 
if (response.data === 'Study Master Saved Successfully')
{ alertService.showDialog('md', 'Message', 'Study has been created', 'success', 'studyList');
} else 
{ alertService.showDialog('sm', 'Alert', 'Study Details Not Added Successfully', 'warning'); } }
```

Comment: Why do you post this as an answer? Please get aware of the basic on stackoverflow.